# Simple API Gateway with two microservices in Java

Tags: java, microservices, quarkus, gateway

I wrote two microservices in Java Quarkus:

1. user-microservice running on port 8080
2. game-microservice running on port 8282

and I successfully test their endpoints with POSTMAN.

Now I need to build a simple API Gateway running for example on port 8000, and when I receive a request on localhost:8000 the Gateway will fetch for me the needed data from the two microservices and show me them on 8000 on POSTMAN. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you *need* to build one or *want* to build one? Because there's plenty of already existing solutions to this problem.

Comment: Yes i saw many solutions, but i need to build one in-house.

Comment: Ok so basically you should 1) Listen on port 8000; 2) Analyze the request; 3) Call the appropriate microservice forwarding the parameters; 4) Fetch the response; 5) Send it back to the client. If you have any problem with one of this steps please [edit] your question to specificy which step and what problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a API gateway microservice using Spring Cloud Gateway (spring-cloud-starter-gateway)

All you would need to do is to define routes in application.yaml (or properties) for a very trivial API gateway.

An example of the application.yaml for routes is as follows:

routes:

- id: demo

  ```
    - id: connect
      uri: https://connect-dev.com
      predicates:
        - Path= /connect/**
      filters:
        - StripPrefix= 1
  ```

uri: The endpoint you want to redirect to
predicates: An identifier for the service you want to redirect to
Filters.stripPrefix: removes the predicate, such that the downstream service can map the API to the relevant resource.

Here is an article with more details: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway

Answer (score -1):

Believe me . if you just need a simple gateway . nigix will be helpful, you just should rewrite the config file, and start it. it's done.

But if you want to build a project called gateway. you might need zookeepr and  rpc framework for your diff port of every app. your port sould be store with zk or redis. if it runing even in diff device, ip shold be store, too.

Read the document of dubbo or eureka might help you.